# Select individual records only

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have a table as such

```
custno, type, color
A1234, B, Red
A1234, C, Blue
A1277, B, Red
A1288, A, Black
A1288, B, Red
A1289, A, Black
```

I need to retrieve only the unique records A1277 and A1289 that are only found once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display the `custNO` on the result list,

```
SELECT  custNo
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY custNO
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
```

but if you want to get the whole row,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  custNo
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY custNO
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
        ) b ON a.custNo = b.custNo
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d53e0/2)

Comment: How could I then only select those where Type = 'B'

Comment: Yes, looks good.  I have a customer table CTABLE linked on custNo, where would I place this join?  I tried to add at the end of the inner join but this reduced my result qty.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT custno
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY custno
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/613143/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as this will prevent costly join operation--

`SELECT custno,type,color FROM
(
SELECT  custno, type, color, COUNT(custno) OVER(PARTITION BY custno) CNT
            FROM    tableName
)TMP WHERE CNT=1`