# select individual records based on aggregated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have following table

```
EmployeeID            Salary                      Date
-----------           ----------------            -----------
37                    45000.00                    2015-03-11 
102                   36500.00                    2015-03-11 
103                   43000.00                    2015-03-11 
104                   45000.00                    2015-03-11 
105                   40000.00                    2015-03-11 
37                    45000.00                    2015-04-11 
102                   36500.00                    2015-04-11 
103                   43000.00                    2015-04-11 
104                   45000.00                    2015-04-11 
105                   40000.00                    2015-04-11
```

I want to retrieve records whose "Sum Of Salary" crosses 80000, so the desired output is

```
EmployeeID            Salary                      Date
-----------           ----------------            -----------
37                    45000.00                    2015-03-11 
103                   43000.00                    2015-03-11 
104                   45000.00                    2015-03-11 
37                    45000.00                    2015-04-11 
103                   43000.00                    2015-04-11 
104                   45000.00                    2015-04-11
```

I have achieved it in following way:

1. Store the aggregated results into a table variable.
2. INNER join between the original table & table variable

   ```
   DECLARE @tmpAggregatedSalaries TABLE
   (
       EmployeeID          INT,
       SumOfSalary         DECIMAL(18, 2)
   )

   INSERT INTO @tmpAggregatedSalaries
   SELECT sal.EmployeeID
       , SUM(sal.Salary) AS SumOfSalary
   FROM Salaries sal
   GROUP BY sal.EmployeeID

   SELECT sal.*
       FROM Salaries sal
       INNER JOIN @tmpAggregatedSalaries aggrSal ON sal.EmployeeID = aggrSal.EmployeeID
           AND aggrSal.SumOfSalary > 80000
   ```

As far as I know, storing temporary results to work upon is preferred over Inline queries, so I chose "table variable". Please suggest me more optimized versions.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Tim I'm using sql-server 2012.

Comment: Take a look at the other answer if you want to use window functions.  These two options are basically it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a `GROUP BY` subquery to identify all employees whose sum of salary be greater than 80000 to filter off records from your table which you don't want to see.

```
SELECT t1.EmployeeID,
       t1.Salary,
       t1.Date
FROM Salaries t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EmployeeID
    FROM Salaries
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
    HAVING SUM(Salary) > 80000
) t2
    ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
```

Comment: there's already a post on SO presenting the same way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364846/select-individual-records-only, but I seriously doubt its performance when records increased to thousands or more

Comment: If you have indices setup properly, then I see no reason why this query would not be acceptable.

Comment: well, in that case, don't you think Indexes & Temp tables together might play a better role??

Comment: I can't answer this question without knowing more about how and where you plan to use the query.  Do you plan on calling it from your application layer?  If so, then doing it "inline" is the main option.  If you plan on running it as a DBA from the console, then yes maybe you could use a temp table.

Comment: Alright, let it be Application Layer, but will you please provide me a reference that could justify your opinion. because I've encountered scenarios where I had to change inline queries into combination of Temp tables & Indexes, just to optimize retrieval time...

Comment: In MySQL temporary tables only exist during a given client session.  Since your app may have many different users, with each user having a new database session, the temporary table would need to be created again each time.  Rather, you would rather query a table which persists across sessions.

Comment: @GG avoid temp tables whenever possible

Comment: @Drew As far as I know, temp tables are really helpful while dealing with temporary results and keep the query performance intact. Please let me know if there's any drawback of same..

Comment: Temporary tables have the following problems (1) creating and dropping DDL performance compared to sessioned permanent (2) the mentality mindset of even using them which typically stems from being new to SQL

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `SUM()` [window](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/) function:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Salaries
(
    EmployeeID INT
    , Salary DECIMAL(10, 2)
    , [Date] DATE
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Salaries PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID, [Date])
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Salaries (EmployeeID, Salary, [Date])
VALUES (37, 45000.00, '2015-03-11')
    , (102, 36500.00, '2015-03-11')
    , (103, 43000.00, '2015-03-11')
    , (104, 45000.00, '2015-03-11')
    , (105, 40000.00, '2015-03-11')
    , (37,  45000.00, '2015-04-11')
    , (102, 36500.00, '2015-04-11')
    , (103, 43000.00, '2015-04-11')
    , (104, 45000.00, '2015-04-11')
    , (105, 40000.00, '2015-04-11');

SELECT S.EmployeeID, S.Salary, S.[Date]
FROM (
    SELECT EmployeeID, Salary, [Date], SUM(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID) AS SalarySum
    FROM dbo.Salaries
    ) AS S
WHERE S.SalarySum > 80000;
```

This query will calculate total salary for each employee and later one just filter out ones that earned less than 80000 in total.

Result:

```
EmployeeID  Salary                                  Date
----------- --------------------------------------- ----------
37          45000.00                                2015-03-11
37          45000.00                                2015-04-11
103         43000.00                                2015-03-11
103         43000.00                                2015-04-11
104         45000.00                                2015-04-11
104         45000.00                                2015-03-11
```

Of course you can use an inline query like [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) has suggested:

```
SELECT S.EmployeeID, S.Salary, S.[Date]
FROM dbo.Salaries AS S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(Salary) AS SalarySum
    FROM dbo.Salaries
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
    ) AS T
    ON T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID
WHERE T.SalarySum > 80000;
```

For such small result set, the latter one seems to perform better by looking at execution plans. You'd have to compare it on your actual data to decide which one performs better. Attaching plans for both queries:

#### Using window functions:

[image]

#### Classic one:

[image]

Comment: thanks for such a nice description. But whether we use window() function, it is an inline query itself. I just wanted to know alternatives to Inline Query & temp tables..

Comment: @GGArora I see that. Well, you can always move inline query to common table expression, but that would not change a thing. By showing window functions, I simply wanted to point out yet another approach to fulfill your needs. :-)

Comment: Well, that means we have Inline Queries, temporary tables(temp table, table variable, CTE). but no third option in such scenarios..